# Method to close a lot of closeable objects

Tags: java, jdbc

I wrote a method that closes 3 closeable types:

- `java.sql.Connection`
- `java.sql.PreparedStatement`
- `java.sql.ResultSet`

```
   public static void closeAll(final Connection connection, 
                            final PreparedStatement statement, 
                            final ResultSet rs)
         throws SQLException
   {
      try
      {
         if (rs != null)
         {
            rs.close();
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (statement != null)
            {
               statement.close();
            }
         }
         finally
         {
            if (connection != null)
            {
               connection.close();
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Is there a way to simplify it in Java 6?

In Java 7 I can use an `AutoCloseable` interface:

```
   public static void closeAll(final AutoCloseable ... closeables)
   {
      if (closeables != null && closeables.length > 0)
      {
         for (final AutoCloseable closeable: closeables)
         {
            try
            {
               closeable.close();
            }
            catch (final Exception ex)
            {
               // log it
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Is this a better solution?

Comment: You should look into the *try-with-resources* statement first, introduced in Java 7, it will take care of closing your resources that implement `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: @skiwi Yes, I know about *try-with-resources*. But question is about `Java 6+`. I cann't use 2-nd solution and *try-with-resources*

Comment: If you knew about `try-with-resources`, why did you propose that weird `closeAll` method? The point of the **auto** closeable interface is that it's done automatically. You should have just used the `Closeable` interface if you're doing it manually -- it's been there since Java 5.

Comment: @DavidS In java 6, `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` don't extend `Closeable`. `Closeable` is used for `java.io` package

Comment: Oh I see. In Java 6 those classes do not implement any interface for the `close` method. I understand the difficulty now.

Answer (score 3):

A `ResultSet` is closed automatically when the `Statement` that created it is closed.
A `Statement` is closed automatically when the `Connection` that created it is closed.

If you want to close everything, just close the `Connection`.

Answer (score 2):

Check Guava Closer (poor man's try-with-resources for jdk6):  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained

Something like this should work (not tested)

```
Closer closer = Closer.create();
try {
  closer.register(connection);
  closer.register(statement);
  closer.register(rs);

  // do stuff with in and out
} catch (Throwable e) { // must catch Throwable
  throw closer.rethrow(e);
} finally {
  closer.close();
}
```

However, this is still boilerplate and I wouldn't write such code. For example if you are using Spring check JdbcTemplate to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is but I think for Java 7 this is how you do it.

Here, I am querying some "testtable" to get some data.

The try-with-resource statement does all the connection-closing headache for you. You just need to sit, relax and go through your logs for error messages ;)

```
    private void getDataFromTable(String date)
      throws Exception
    {
      try (Connection db = ds.getConnection()) {


        try (PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement("select * from testtable")) {
          ps.setString(1, date);

          try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while(rs.next){
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RunTimeException("Something went wrong here", ex);
      }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP is using java 6 see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57182/#comment102088_57182

Comment: aahh. didn't see that comment.  Thanks